# unable to resolve getter method

Tags: java

I'm learning java as a beginner and I'm trying to create a program that calculates your future age as an exercise.

**I have the following issue:**

Error:(14, 64) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getYear()
location: class ageProgram

I can't seem to get my getter methods eventho they are declared public.

**ageProgram.java:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ageProgram {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter your birth year");
        int yearBirth = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter a (future) year");
        int yearTo = keyboard.nextInt();

        ageCalculator agecalculator = new ageCalculator(yearBirth, yearTo);

        if (yearBirth > yearTo) {
            System.out.println("You will be born in %s years", getYear());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You are %s years old", getYear());
        }
    }
}
```

**ageCalculator.java:**

```
public class ageCalculator {
        public ageCalculator(int yearBirth, int yearTo) {
            if (yearBirth > yearTo) {
                int year = (yearBirth - yearTo);
                year = year.toString();
            } else {
                int year = (yearTo - yearBirth);
                year = year.toString();
            }
        }
        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }
        }
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong... I tried to check for solutions at similar / other questions on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have not prefixed the method by the object that invokes it : `agecalculator.getYear()` Calling `getYear()` from a static method looks for a `getYear()` static method in the current class (or its parent class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

ageProgram.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ageProgram {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter your birth year");
        int yearBirth = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter a (future) year");
        int yearTo = keyboard.nextInt();

        ageCalculator agecalculator = new ageCalculator(yearBirth, yearTo);

        if (yearBirth > yearTo) {
            System.out.format("You will be born in %s years", agecalculator.getYear());
        } else {
            System.out.format("You are %s years old", agecalculator.getYear());
        }
    }
}
```

ageCalculator.java

```
public class ageCalculator {
    String yearText;
    public ageCalculator(int yearBirth, int yearTo) {
        if (yearBirth > yearTo) {
            int year = (yearBirth - yearTo);
            yearText = String.valueOf(year);
        } else {
            int year = (yearTo - yearBirth);
            yearText = String.valueOf(year);
        }
    }
    public String getYear() {
        return yearText;
    }
}
```

if you don't understand it, i can explain

edit: i didn't get it at first but the above answer is also correct. you should use agecalculater.getYear() to call the method
edit: you should start a class name with a capital letter. and you can use

```
yearText = String.valueOf(yearBirth - yearTo);
```

instead of

```
int year = (yearTo - yearBirth);
yearText = String.valueOf(year);
```

Comment: Why would you add the String yearText as the variable is not used? Could you explain the suggested solution? Thanks

Comment: answer of your question: you should set a variable for other methods to reach it. if you set it inside a method it is not possible to used by other methods.

an other thing is if you want to call a method of a class you have to call it from the class. in our case it is agecalculator.getYear()

Comment: use agecalculator.getYear() instead of getYear() in main method

Answer (score 1):

You must tell which object the method `getYear` you are referring to. In your example, you must call `getYear` as `agecalculator.getYear()` and all should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However now I get the following error: Error:(14, 80) java: non-static method getYear() cannot be referenced from a static context. Any suggestions?

Comment: See [buraksivrikaya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355069/unable-to-resolve-getter-method/44355116?noredirect=1#comment75713205_44355156) answer. He solved well the syntax errors in `ageCalculator.java`.